# Properties of centralization in group theory

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing

**Recall** Let $C\subseteq G$ where $G$ is a group. If $x\in G$ for any $c\in C,$ $xc=cx,$ then $x$ centralizes $C$

$$C_G(C) := \{x \in G : \text{ for any } x\in C, xc=cx \}$$

Clearly,

$$C_G(C)=\bigcap_{c\in C}C_G(c)$$

> Prove that
>
> a) $C\subseteq C_G(C_G(C))$
>
> b) If $C\subseteq D$ then $C_G(D)\subseteq C_G(C)$
>
> c) $C_G(C_G(C_G(C)))=C_G(C)$

My Proof-trying:

a) Let $c\in C$. We will show $c\in C_G(C_G(C)).$ We need to show for any $x\in C_G(C),$ $xc=cx.$

Note that $x\in C_G(C)$ $\iff$ for any $c\in C$ $xc=cx$ by definition.

Hence $c\in C_G(C_G(C)).$ Therefore $C\subseteq C_G(C_G(C)).$

b) Assume $C\subseteq D.$ Let $x\in C_G(D).$ Then for any $d\in D$, we have $dx=xd.$ Since $C\subseteq D$, then for any $c\in C$, we have $cx=xc.$ So we are done.

c)I couldn't show it.

**Can you check my proof, if there is a false, can you edit? Can you help for c)?** Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proofs for a) and b) are OK.
For c), first, apply b) to the inclusion a) to obtain one inclusion.

Second, to obtain the reverse inclusion, apply a)  to $C_G(C)$.

Comment: Assume $C\subseteq C_G(C_G(C))$, by the b), then we have $C_G(C_G(C_G(C)))\subseteq C_G(C).$  Now for the reverse inclusion, if we can assume $C_G(C_G(C))\subseteq C$, then we get $C_G(C)\subseteq C_G(C_G(C_G(C)))$, but I don't know that we can assume this. Can you help?

Comment: could you see my comment?

Comment: I saw it just  a moment ago. I don't know whether we can assume this hypothesis. What I suggested in my answer was very simple: apply  a) to $C_G(C)$ in the place of $C$ (unrelated: it would be less confusional to denote the centraliser of $C$ the traditional way – $Z_G(C)$).

Answer (score 1):

> **Proposition** Let $H,K$ subgroups of a group $G$, then the following hold.
> $(a)$ If $H \leq K$ then $C_G(K) \leq C_G(H)$.
> $(b)$ $H \leq C_G(C_G(H))$.
> $(c)$ $C_G(H)=C_G(C_G(C_G(H)))$.
> $(d)$ If $H$ is abelian, then $C_G(C_G(H)) \subseteq C_G(H)$.
> $(e)$ If $H$ is abelian then $Z(C_G(H))=C_G(C_G(H))$, in particular $C_G(C_G(H))$ is abelian.
> Conversely, if $Z(C_G(H))=C_G(C_G(H))$, then $H$ is abelian.

**Proof** $(a)$ is obvious.
$(b)$ Let $h \in H$, and $x \in C_G(H)$, then $xh=hx$ by definition, hence $h$ centralizes $C_G(H)$.
$(c)$ Replacing $H$ by $C_G(H)$ in (b) we obtain $C_G(C_G(H)) \subseteq C_G(C_G(C_G(H)))$. But applying (a) to (b) yields the reverse inclusion: $C_G(C_G(C_G(H))) \subseteq C_G(C_G(H))$.
$(d)$ If $H$ is abelian, then obviously $H \subseteq C_G(H)$. Hence, by (a) we are done.
$(e)$ Observe that in general $Z(H)=H \cap C_G(H)$. If $H$ happens to be abelian, then, by applying (d) we have $Z(C_G(H))=C_G(H) \cap C_G(C_G(H))=C_G(C_G(H)).$ The converse statement follows from (b).

Comment: But note that the $C$ and the $D$ in the question were subsets of $G$, not necessarily subgroups.

Comment: Ah yes true, overlooked that, but (a), (b) and (c) still hold when $H$ and $K$ are *subsets* and $H \subseteq K$.